# Call Google Maps with Url from Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-maps

i call the url of googlemaps to show a position to a given lat and long. 
How can i mark this position on the map with a pin ?

```
 NSString *latlong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", einBetrieb.lat, einBetrieb.lng];
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%@",
      [latlong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Regard Caglar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this url:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@", [latlong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

That should get you what you want. Replace the "ll" with a "q"

Comment: you guys are very fast and helpful. @all: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need to use the mapkit api to solve your problems. Launching the Maps App externally will not give you the access you desire

you can do a quick search of StackOverFlow to find solutions, here is the first one I found

[iPhone MapKit - update annotations coordinates and map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873755/iphone-mapkit-update-annotations-coordinates-and-map)

Answer (score 0):

You should use MapKit to display map on iPhone, you will have greater flexibility and faster integration.

mapView being a MKMapView instance, you will have to manipulate your string to extract long and lat then

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D loc;
loc.latitude = extractedLatFromString;
loc.longitude = extractedLongFromString;
AddressAnnotation *pin = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:loc];
[mapView addAnnotation:pin];
```

should do the job

Comment: @logancautrell : He definitely should ;-) !